# How can I change geolocation in virtual device manager?

Tags: android-studio, geolocation, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to change the original geolocation to Germany, click "set location" - shows Belarus (my current location)
Restarting the emulator via power off doesn't help either

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq5i8.jpg

I need to change the geolocation before launching .apk, but it doesn't work. Maybe someone knows how? And will it be necessary to do this every time the emulator is launched, or is it possible to set up the geolocation of Germany forever somewhere?

I'm trying to change the original geolocation to Germany, click "set location" - shows Belarus (my current location)
Restarting the emulator via power off doesn't help either

I also tried with Extended Controls - Proxy, even it says "Success" - internet connection is just does not work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJtFz.png